# Contact Form 7 Redirect to different URL on form submit depending upon dropdown select

Tags: contact-form-7

I am using this code for dropdown menu in Contact Form 7:

```
[select* menu-student id:menustudent include_blank "Student" "Professional"]
```

I want if one select Student, then after form submission, it'll redirect to the student page and if one select Professional, it'll go to the professional page after form submission.

I have used this code as mentioned here.

This is the code I have added:

```
<script>
inputs = event.detail.inputs;
inputs.forEach( function(el) {
    if ( el.name == 'menu-student' ) {
        if ( el.value == 'Student' ) {
            location.href = 'https://google.com';
        } else if ( el.value == 'Professional' ) {
            location.href = 'https://facebook.com';
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But it is not redirecting for me.

Can someone please point me where I am doing wrong?

I have also used the below script without any result:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  var lpLocation =  document.getElementById("menustudent").value;
  if (lpLocation == "Student") {
    location = 'https://facebook.com/';
  } else if (lpLocation == "Professional") {
    location = 'https://google.com/';
  }
}, false )
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the above code a bit and it worked for me.

Here is the code for anyone need this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  var lpLocation =  document.getElementById("menustudent").value;
  if (lpLocation == "Student") {
    location = 'https://google.com';
  } else if (lpLocation == "Professional") {
    location = 'https://facebook.com';
  }
}, false );
</script>
```

You need to change the ID and selections as per yours.

Thank you.